# Create a heat Map in SAS

Tags: graph, sas, heatmap

I am looking to create a heat map in SAS.  I have a large data set of x,y coordinates and that's it.  From reading into everything, I need to create a "count" for the coordinates using something like this:

```
 proc kde data=dataSet;
     bivar X Y / out=outputDataSet;
 run;
```

Next, I need to create a template for the heatchart--I have found this sample code, but I'm not sure what everything is doing:

```
proc template;
   define statgraph heatmapparm;
     begingraph;
       layout overlay;
         heatmapparm x=value1 y=value2 colorresponse=count /
             name="heatmapparm" xbinaxis=false ybinaxis=false;
         continuouslegend "heatmapparm" / location=outside valign=bottom;
       endlayout;
     endgraph;
end;
run;
```

I'm assuming I need to insert my variables into the x and y spots, and the count into the colorresponse place and then use a code like this to get the heatmap:

```
proc sgrender data=outputDataSet template=heatmapparm;
run;
```

This code leads to an error message and no graph output because it is "missing an argument."  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rick Wicklin does a good job explaining this on his blog, [The DO Loop](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/08/18/heat-map-in-sas/).

You should look up a tutorial on Graph Template Language (GTL), such as Sanjay Matange (the lead developer of the ODS Graphics system including GTL).  He's written a book on the topic, or you can read his papers, such as [this introduction](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/sgf2008/gtl.pdf).

Basically, yes, you should fill in the x= and y= with your x/y variables, colorresponse= with the variable that defines the count (how red/blue to make it).

Here's an example.  Here we use `dynamic variables`, which mean you can define the relevant variable in the `SGRENDER` step.  Rick shows this in his blog post, I use a slightly simplified version.  You can likely use the `PROC TEMPLATE` exactly as is, just changing the SGRENDER to refer to your dataset and your variables.  The `test` dataset is just made-up data that will generate an interesting heat map.

```
proc template;
   define statgraph heatmapparm;
    dynamic _X _Y _Z;
     begingraph;
       layout overlay;
         heatmapparm x=_X y=_Y colorresponse=_Z/
             name="heatmapparm" xbinaxis=false ybinaxis=false;
         continuouslegend "heatmapparm" / location=outside valign=bottom;
       endlayout;
     endgraph;
  end;
run;

data test;
  call streaminit(7);
  do x = 1 to 10;
    do y = 1 to 10;
      count_var = rand('Normal',(x+y)/2);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;


proc sgrender data=test template=heatmapparm;
dynamic _X='x' _Y='y' _Z='count_var';
run;
```